# Signal handling in Uvicorn with FastAPI

Tags: python, signals, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

I have an app using `Uvicorn` with `FastAPI`. I have also some connections open (e.g. to `MongoDB`). I want to gracefully close these connections once some signal occurs (`SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`).

My `server.py` file:

```py
import uvicorn
import fastapi
import signal
import asyncio

from source.gql import gql


app = fastapi.FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"], allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])
app.mount("/graphql", gql)

# handle signals
HANDLED_SIGNALS = (
    signal.SIGINT,
    signal.SIGTERM
)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for sig in HANDLED_SIGNALS:
    loop.add_signal_handler(sig, _some_callback_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, port=6900)
```

Unfortunately, the way I try to achieve this is not working. When I try to `Ctrl+C` in terminal, nothing happens. I believe it is caused because `Uvicorn` is started in different thread...

What is the correct way of doing this? I have noticed `uvicorn.Server.install_signal_handlers()` function, but wasn't lucky in using it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FastAPI allows defining event handlers (functions) that need to be executed before the application starts up, or when the application is shutting down. Thus, you could use the  `shutdown` event, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#shutdown-event):

```
@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():
    # close connections here
```

### Update

Since `startup` and `shutdown` events are now deprecated (and might be removed in the future), one could use a [`lifespan` function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ru/advanced/events/#lifespan-function) instead. Examples and details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804).

Comment: More about how those events work here: https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html

Comment: Keep in mind that a `shutdown` event is only called after all active connections are closed. From the [ASGI Shutdown documentation](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html): _"Sent to the application when the server has stopped accepting connections and closed all active connections."_