# How to download a large file on startup in FastAPI without blocking the event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, fastapi, downloadfileasync

I would like to download a large file when the application starts up but it should happen parallelly. As in an actual app startup, the app shouldn't wait for the file download to complete.

What I am currently doing is:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

items = {}


@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    //Download file
```

Now this seems to work but I get a lot of critical worker timeout errors. I wanted to know if there is someway that I can do the download just when the application starts but also do it in a way that it doesn't make the application wait for the download to finish.

Comment: you can use Python's built-in `threading ` or `asyncio` to perform the download asynchronously

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

This answer derives code and information from the following answers. Hence, please take a look at them for more details and explanation:

1. [How to initialise a global object or variable and reuse it in every FastAPI endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804)
2. [What is the proper way to make downstream Https requests inside of Uvicorn/FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804)
3. [Is having a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor call dangerous in a FastAPI endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804)
4. [FastAPI python: How to run a thread in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804)
5. [Return File/Streaming response from online video URL in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804)
6. [FastAPI UploadFile is slow compared to Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804)
7. [How to download a large file using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804)
8. [How to run another application within the same running event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804)

The solutions provided below use the `httpx` library, which provides a powerful HTTP client library for Python, an `async` API and support for both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. The `aiofiles` library is also used for handling file operations (such as writing files to disk) in `asyncio` applications. Public videos (large files) for testing the solutions can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657).

### Solution 1

Use this solution if you would like to reuse the HTTP client across your application.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import httpx


async def download_large_file(client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    large_file_url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'
    path = 'save_to/video.mp4'
    req = client.build_request('GET', large_file_url)
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    async with aiofiles.open(path, 'wb') as f:
        async for chunk in r.aiter_raw():
            await f.write(chunk)
    await r.aclose()

    
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        asyncio.create_task(download_large_file(client))
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def home():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.get('/download')
async def download_some_file(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client  # reuse the HTTP client
    req = client.build_request('GET', 'https://www.example.com')
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(r.aiter_raw(), background=BackgroundTask(r.aclose))
```

### Solution 2

Use this solution if you don't need reusing the HTTP client, but only need using it at startup.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import httpx


async def download_large_file():
    large_file_url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'
    path = 'save_to/video.mp4'
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        async with client.stream('GET', large_file_url) as r:
            async with aiofiles.open(path, 'wb') as f:
                async for chunk in r.aiter_raw():   
                    await f.write(chunk)


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    asyncio.create_task(download_large_file())
    yield


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def home():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say for example take 10GB file (https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin) to download on startup.

As the application starts, it triggers an asynchronous download task using `aiohttp`, fetch a file from `https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin` and saving it as downloaded_file.

The download occurs in chunks, and this background process allows the application to initiate other tasks and respond to incoming requests without waiting for the download to complete.

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI
import aiohttp

app = FastAPI()

async def download_large_file():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        url = "https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin"
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                with open('downloaded_file', 'wb') as file:
                    while True:
                        chunk = await response.content.read(1024)
                        if not chunk:
                            break
                        file.write(chunk)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(download_large_file())
```

Hope this block of code helps.

Comment: Thanks,let me try that and respond back