# how to run FastAPI app and TCP server as async tasks within the same FastAPI event loop

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, fastapi

what I would like to achieve is that the TCP server creates multiple threads and each thread listens on a different port, 8001, 8002, and 8003 in this case, and passing the raw data received through a TCP socket to a client through websocket. now, I am making sure the end-to-end process works as expected such as the following.

client1 (in instance 1) -> TCP -> server (in instance2) -> websocket -> client2 (in instance2)

when running the command, `uvicorn main:app`, the Fast API server is successfully up and running in localhost and a websocket connection is also confirmed between the server and client with port 8000. however, `start_tcp_server` does not seem to get fired off. a socket connection always fails when a client attempts to send data to the server. the client and the server exist in different ec2 instances, but I have already confirmed that they can communicate each other with the instance IP address of the server instance.
could anyone possibly point me out what's wrong with my code? thank you in advance!

```
# server.py

import asyncio
import globals

async def handle_client(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        await globals.websocket_manager.broadcast(data.decode('utf-8'))
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

async def start_tcp_server(port):
    print("starting tcp server...")
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '0.0.0.0', port)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
```

```
# globals.py

import threading
from websocket_manager import WebSocketManager

data_storage = {}
data_lock = threading.Lock()
websocket_manager = WebSocketManager()
```

```
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
import asyncio
import globals
from server import start_tcp_server
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def startup_event(app: FastAPI):
    # Start TCP servers on multiple ports
    print("start TCP servers")
    ports = [8001, 8002, 8003]
    yield
    await asyncio.gather(*(start_tcp_server(port) for port in ports))

app = FastAPI(lifespan=startup_event)

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("about to connect to websocket")
    await globals.websocket_manager.connect(websocket)
    print("websocket:", websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            await websocket.receive_text()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"WebSocket Error: {e}")
        globals.websocket_manager.disconnect(websocket)
```

```
# websocket_manager.py

from fastapi import WebSocket
from typing import List

class WebSocketManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: List[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def broadcast(self, data: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(data)
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start servers after yield in lifespan. This part will be executed only when your application is shutting down .You should run servers before `yield`.

Try this (you should add some code to send to your servers 'stop' signals):

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def startup_event(app: FastAPI):
    # Start TCP servers on multiple ports
    print("start TCP servers")
    ports = [8001, 8002, 8003]
    servers = [asyncio.create_task(start_tcp_server(port)) for port in ports]
    yield
    # TODO: Send 'stop' signal to servers
    await asyncio.gather(*servers)
```

Full example:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from fastapi import FastAPI

class Server():
    def __init__(self):
        self._stop = False

    async def start_tcp_server(self, port):
        while not self._stop:
            print(f"ping ({port=})")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True


@asynccontextmanager
async def startup_event(app: FastAPI):
    # Start TCP servers on multiple ports
    print("start TCP servers")
    ports = [8001, 8002, 8003]
    server = Server()
    servers = [asyncio.create_task(server.start_tcp_server(port)) for port in ports]
    yield
    server.stop()    # TODO: Send 'stop' signal to servers
    await asyncio.gather(*servers)


app = FastAPI(
    lifespan=startup_event
)
```

Comment: hmm, in your case, the task for start_tcp_server is just created, but not executed before shutting down the application, so the server is not receiving data from clients through TCP using socket isn't it? but I would like to run TCP server and Fast API server concurrently.

Comment: `asyncio.create_task(...)` creates and runs task in the current loop (in background). So, it should work.

Comment: There was a mistake in my code, I should have used list comprehension instead of generator. Now it works

Comment: when running `uvicorn main:app` with your revised code, I still don't see the print statement, `print("starting tcp server...")`, in `server.py,` and 
the TCP client is still not able to send data to the server.

Comment: on console,
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [37546] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [37548]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
start TCP servers
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py:44: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start_tcp_server' was never awaited
  return loop.run_until_complete(main)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
INFO:     Application startup complete.

Comment: Added full working example. I run this on `FastAPI 0.105.0` and `uvicorn 0.24.0.post1` . It works