# How can I run a function once after starting the FastAPI server?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I need to start the `create_data` function once after the FastAPI `app` is started. I tried using [lifespan](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan) but found it not useful because `FastAPI` only starts working after `create_data` is finished. How can I run FastAPI before `create_data`?

```py
import time

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

DATA = {"value": ""}

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def get_root():
    return DATA


def create_data():
    time.sleep(2)
    DATA["value"] = "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_data()  # Working, but I need to run this function only after the Web server is started
    uvicorn.run(app)
    create_data()  # Not working, the function is not being called
```

Comment: Related answers to the link above can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) provides details and solutions around `async def` and normal `def` functions/endpoints in FastAPI that might prove helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way according to the documentation is to use `@app.on_event("startup")` decorator and `BackgroundTasks`. Do note that this will actually run before the server is ready to receive requests.

```
from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    background_tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    background_tasks.add_task(create_data)
    await background_tasks()
```

Reference:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-events/

Comment: It's not working as intended. The web server is waiting for background tasks, but I don't want it to wait for them.

Comment: You can remove the `await` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [lifespan](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan). This way you can specify what you want to do during init and during shutdown.

For your code it should go like

```
import time

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

DATA = {"value": ""}

def create_data():
    time.sleep(2)
    DATA["value"] = "Hello World!"

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    create_data()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/")
def get_root():
    return DATA


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_data()  # Working, but I need to run this function only after the Web server is started
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Refer to the lifespan and events for more details https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan

Comment: Your example is missing the `yield` keyword in the `lifespan` function."

Comment: It's not working as intended. The web server is waiting for the `lifespan`, but I no need wait it.