# Stream `.m3u8` or `.mpd` video files as a FastAPI response

Tags: google-cloud-storage, fastapi, http-live-streaming, pre-signed-url, react-player

I have videos on my Google Cloud Storage. I'm using "Google Transcoder API" to generate HLS (`.mpd`) and DASH (`.mpd`) formats for each video.

Now I want to publish these videos on my website (written in React.js) using `react-player`. But as I figured it out, Google Pre-Signed URLs (just like AWS) are public. And my video content should not be downloadable or available through a URL (event with a expiry).

I want to write a FastAPI API as a proxy server to get request from `react-player` and stream videos from Google Cloud Storage.

I want to know:
1- How can I download HLS `.m3u8` or DASH `.mpd` files from Google Cloud Storage, in Python.
2- How can I return the downloaded content, from FastAPI to Front-End.

Where both of these operations, follow the streaming standards and do not download the full video at first.

My videos are not live and are pre-recorded and transcoded.

I found this snippet but I don't know if it's OK or not:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse
import httpx

app = FastAPI()

CLOUD_STORAGE_BASE_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"

async def proxy_video(request: Request):
    path = request.url.path
    video_url = f"{CLOUD_STORAGE_BASE_URL}{path}"

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(video_url, stream=True)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for non-200 responses

    return StreamingResponse(
        response.aiter_raw(),
        status_code=response.status_code,
        headers=response.headers,
        media_type=response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
    )

@app.get("/{path:path}")
async def serve_video(path: str):
    return await proxy_video(request)
```

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)

Comment: Check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object) for downloading objects from `Cloud storage`. Also have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/livestream/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-hls#create-input-python)